# How to separate column data to copy from one table to other table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin. I have two tables: STUDENT and STUD.

- STUD consists of a column DATE_TIME where the date and time are
  joined together.
- STUDENT consists of two columns: DATE and TIME.

I need to split the DATE_TIME from STUD table so that I can copy the DATE and TIME individually to STUDENT table.

How do I do that?

Comment: `insert into student (date_col,time_col) select date_time::date, date_time::time from stud;`

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Comment: @VaoTsun gave you the answer. If you want to understand it, you can ask for an explanation or study some SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!
I've also understand it after looking at your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into student (date_col,time_col) select date_time::date, date_time::time from stud;
```

should work for you

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I've also understand it after looking at your solution. Thanks!